# Blank Control Panel and most system icons are missing

Tags: windows-7, passwords, user-accounts, login, icons

I have recently got into a strange problem with a specific user account(standard, non-admin) in a Windows 7 64Bit installation. Desktop icons in that account is shown without a shortcut icon, actually they have the place vacant but it is like the shortcut icon is missing(Image attached) and not icons in My Computer and it is like having a transparent icon for some folders, but some others are fine. So I thought this is a problem with the Icon cache and tried clearing it to no avail. The account in problem was disabled for quite some time (about one month).
Since the account wasn't that important, I deleted it and created another standard account; but the same problem. For some reason I just opened the control panel and I was surprised to see that it was blank as in the image attached.
[image: Attached image 1]
All this happened while another account(admin account) was working fine. So I thought the problem was with standard accounts and then created a new admin account to no avail.
Now I am at my wit's end here. Can anyone tell me what the real problem is? Or help me identify it?

*While troubleshooting this problem, I had to log out/lock my admin many times and twice when I tried to re-login after entering my password, I was told that the 'referenced account is locked and may not be logged into'. After restarting/logging into another account fixed this. While figuring out the cause for it, I found that the "Maximum Password Age' is set to 42 days in the Group Policy Editor without my knowledge.Even after changing this to  "Password never Expires' that error message was shown once. I haven't tried again since.*
As told by @ Ramhound, I ran an 'sfc' command and the relevant log file portion is posted [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/599cywnkvpjztej/cbs_errors.txt?dl=0)(Dropbox Link)

Comment: Update your question.  I will be removing my comments to avoid unnecessary pings

Comment: Try to [explicitly enable](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16189/configure-what-items-are-available-in-control-panel-or-completely-disable-it-in-windows-7/) the control panel

Comment: @Ramhound I did that, but no change.